# jQuery GET request to PHP failing although PHP is fetching the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I having written a php script which makes an SQL query and fetches a list of unique names from the database.

I am making an AJAX `GET` request using jQuery to the php script. When I check resources in the console I see that the php script is being called, and when I check the response it contains a list of unique names.

However, the jquery `GET` request is failing, and is displaying an error message in the console.

It may be easier and clearer to look at my code, as I have no idea what is the issue here. Please see code below.

**php**

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $servername = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM customer";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo json_encode(array('customer' => $row["name"]));
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    } 
    $conn->close();
?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'getcustomers.php',        
   success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
   },
   error: function() {
     console.log('error');
   }
});
```

In the console it simply says `error`, meaning it has executed the `error` function.

When I load the php file in the browser it displays the following.

```
{"name":"Peter"}{"name":"Alan"}{"name":"Mike"}
```

Comment: Can you include the error shown in the console?

Comment: Just run the file `getcustomers.php` directly from a browser and detect the error

Comment: @SherinJose yes, when i run the php file all the names are showing as expected - `{"name":"Mike"}{"name":"Alan"}{"name":"Peter"}`

Comment: The returned JSON is likely invalid

Comment: @madebydavid i think it looks like it is incorrect, it doesn't look quite right. Perhaps there is something wrong in the `while` loop

Comment: I think the issue is that you're not returning one JSON array with all the objects, instead you're returning a lot of individual objects. I'm not sure how JS likes that. Perhaps you can first try creating a PHP array containing the data you want in the while loop (simply add to the array every iteration) and then once you're completely done json_encode that array and echo it.

Comment: That JSON returned is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON response is not a valid one. You are printing each data row on each iteration. So replace the while statement with this one,

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $return = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $return[] = array('customer' => $row["name"]);
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: this was the issue. top man sherin! my php aint great, i gotta be honest. understand and get it now!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: will get ur green tick when it allows me ;-)

Comment: But here you should keep a common format for the output. I mean for `num_rows > 0` and `==0`. Use JSON for both responses

Answer (score 0):

Considering your script returns any result (I hope you've tried running it in broswer) then you can use something like this:

```
$.get('path/to/file/filename.php').done(function(response) {
    $('#exampleDiv').html(response);
});
```

Although, common errors because you must specify the directory path if the php file you're requesting is outside the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

change your error handler function header to the following:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```

then print that and see what the error is

Answer (score 0):

you are echoing json_encode string in side while loop, instead of that you will have to push row in an array and at the end you can echo json string only once.

```
$outputArr = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push(outputArr ,array('customer' => $row["name"]));
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    } 
echo json_encode($outputArr);
```